# API call on Demand or one API Call

Tags: api-design

I have this scenario where there are multiple Help buttons which may or may not be clicked. Now, I am very confused to **send all information**(including the text after user click help buttons) **at once**, or **every time user clicks on one of help button make the API call and send the Response.**
What I see is there can be case of Network Overload when you make Multiple calls but at the same time my seniors suggest  its for - 
1) API Best Practices 
2) Design Practices and 
3) API splitted into Granular Level.

I couldnt find any convincing answer for this anywhere and found only Tutorials for "How to make an API ?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *depends* on the expected network latency (ping time) between your clients and your server. In a high-latency situation with otherwise good bandwidth (e.g. mobile apps), many small requests will perform significantly **worse** than one large one.

Also, having one big request can help with

- better efficiency for [compressing the response](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip);
- avoiding the overhead of the [extra HTTP requests and response headers](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#num_http=).